# LINQ - Conditional navigation in list

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

Let's say I have a list of objects which inherits from the same base class. Is it then possible to get the value that is only specified in one of the subclasses through LINQ? In my example, i want to find the instance which has a specific object which has a specific property?

I have made this example in Linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<A>
    {
        new B
        {
        MyProp = new D{ OtherProp = 1}
        },
        new C(),
        new B
        {
        MyProp = new D{ OtherProp = 30}
        },
    };

    list.Where(x => ....) // how to find the instance where OtherProp == 30 ?

}

public class A
{
    public int JustAprop { get; set; }

}

public class B : A
{
    public D MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class C : A
{

}

public class D
{
    public int OtherProp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That looks like a wrong design to me rather

Comment: Can you elaborate on that @rahul ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1) method and try to cast every item to `B` class, then `OtherProp` value inside `MyProp`

```cs
var result = list.Where(l => (l as B)?.MyProp?.OtherProp == 30);
```

This can be rewritten a little bit using [pattern matching with `is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is)

```cs
var result = list.Where(l => l is B b && b.MyProp.OtherProp == 30);
```

Another way is to use `OfType<T>` method to get a list of `B` instances only, then check `OtherProp` inside `MyProp`

```cs
var result = list.OfType<B>().Where(b => b.MyProp.OtherProp == 30);
```

Comment: That's too tightly coupled .. I mean how you know that it's B's instance has the property set to 30 and not any other type instance?